# Is it unwise to create a predictive model based off 20 independent variables when only 10 variables will be available for future observations?

Tags: neural-networks, econometrics, random-forest, boosted-regression-trees

I've created a predictive model which is based off a historical dataset and has 20 independent variables as the dataset set is comprised of completed projects, so have full information and dataset of the project. In the future, when used to predict outcomes, only 14 variables will be available as the project will be at an early stage, so those variables will be the only ones to change in the predictive formula.

While I can do this, I'm not sure if it is wise or viable, or if it would be better to create a predictive model from the historical dataset that will use only the 14 variables available at that time?

Also, what kind of predictive model would you recommend? I've tried boosted tree, neural networks and partial least squares.  My historical project dataset is 67 projects with around 114 variables

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what kind of variables the unavailable ones are.

If we are talking about variables that would be unavailable at the time one needs to make a prediction, it is often wrong/misleading to include them. E.g. predicting whether a patient dies based on the outcomes of an autopsy with one outcome being "none conducted" is simply nonsense, but the variable could be useful for explaining what happened/why.

If it is variables that would become available later, but not yet, it could make sense to use them (and to see whether one can predict them by what is known/or update the predictions once known1). E.g. predicting whether a project will fail based on the number of pages (or slides) in the full project plan could make sense, but this might not be available at the time of approving the project. However, this might be predictable from the outline/characteristics of the project, or even if not it might be worth updating the prediction once the planning stage is completed (but before some major spending happens). One could argue that perhaps one should just train two models in this case though.

If it is variables that in principle are knowable at the time of prediction, but would not be measured in practice, this is a case of "privileged data" and there's methods proposed for what one could do about that (e.g. train model with all variables and then try to distill the model into one that only has the variables that would be available in practice, ideally on new data - but perhaps on synthetic data).

In terms of models, boosted trees (and random forests) are commonly used models that are often quite decent, but it's usually a good idea to have something like a regularized regression model just to see whether such a simple model is not better.

One certainly should evaluate models properly in the sense that the "to-be-expected" performance would be that with only the smaller set of predictors available. In fact, model evaluation (e.g. through some appropriate form of - possibly nested - cross-validation and/or evaluation on a new test set) would be another thing to very, very carefully think about. Overfitting will be a big potential issue with such a small dataset and more predictors than records, so a validation strategy (that minimizes the negative consequences of overfitting as much as possible and gives an idea of performance with as little bias as possible) needs very careful thinking.

Comment: Overfitting is indeed a huge worry here.  Bootstrapping the whole process, including repetition of any supervised learning steps as well as coefficient estimation, is all important.  Disappointment often follows, as a result of the instability revealed by the bootstrap.  It's better to not publish the result in this case but to gather more data.